# CGFloat variable returns 0.0

Tags: swift, cgfloat

When I try this:

```
let progress: CGFloat = CGFloat(2 / 3)
print(progress)
```

The console returns 0 but the result is 0,66666666667, not 0.... Why is that happening?

When I try:

```
let progress: CGFloat = CGFloat(10 / 3) 
print(progress)
```

It returns 3.0, is that the way how CGFloat works? Is there no way to get comma numbers with CGFLoat?

Comment: You're doing integer division, not floating point.

Comment: You can try CGFloat(2) / 3, it will give you proper result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you leave out converting, this will work perfectly.

```
let progress: CGFloat = 2 / 3
print(progress) //0.666666666666667
```

The reason why this does not work with explicit converting is beause **Swift treats a whole number as an `Int` if it's without context.**

That's exactly what is happening inside converting brackets.